# how to control radiobutton from textfield

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want after i type "0203-ED" in textfield ...two character behind that text can control the radio button..
"ED" character from that text can make one radiobutton which has value="ED" are checked...

what script that can make it work??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var model=$("#tags1").val(); 
 var version[0,0]="JD"; 
 var version[0,1]="87.5-107.9"; 
 var version[1,0]="ED"; 
 var version[1,1]="87.5-108.0"; 
 var version[2,0]="EED"; 
 var version[2,1]="65.0-74.0"; 

 version for (var i = 0; i < version.length; i ++) {
    if (model,lastIndexOf(version[i,0])!=-1) { 
     $("#value").replaceWith("<div id='value'>"+version[i,1]+"</div>"); 
    } else { default: $("#value").replaceWith("<div id='value'></div>")
    } 
 } 
</script>
```

may be it needs to combine with your answer..

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var version[0,0]="JD"; `? That's syntactically wrong.

Comment: i want if inside textfield consist of JD character radio id="JD" can checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var buttons = [];
//store radio buttons in the array buttons
//assign onKeyUp() to `onkeyup` attribute of the text input
function onKeyUp()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("txtInput_id");
  var text = input.value;
  if(text.length < 2)
    return;
  text = text.substring(text.length - 3);
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  {
    if(buttons[i].value == text)
      buttons[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/jaavascript">
var model=$("#tags1").val();
var version[0,0]="JD";
var version[0,1]="87.5-107.9";
var version[1,0]="ED";
var version[1,1]="87.5-108.0";
var version[2,0]="EED";
var version[2,1]="65.0-74.0";
// each version
for (var i = 0; i < version.length; i ++) {
if (model,lastIndexOf(version[i,0])!=-1) {
                                                              $("#value").replaceWith("<div id='value'>"+version[i,1]+"</div>");
                                                }
else {
default:
$("#value").replaceWith("<div id='value'></div>")
}
// end each
}
</script>

Comment: @klox please edit the question and add the code there - select the code and press Ctrl-K to format it